# GraphQL: How to resolve mutation arguments?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

In GraphQL, is it possible to resolve mutation arguments doing something like this:

```
mutationName: {
    type: GraphQLString,
    args: {
        id: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID),
            resolve: async (parent, args, ctx) => {
                return ctx.database.find(parent.id)
            },
        },
    },
    resolve: mutationResolver,
},
```

I know you can use custom scalar types for parsing arguments but the parsing functions don't have access to the context and aren't async.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? It's normal to lookup a record from an id in a query or mutation and then use the record to do something else. However you can't "resolve" an input variable using a resolver.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I'm basically trying to parse resolve arguments. Allowing me to not repeat the same lines of code at the beginning of each resolver.

Comment: Can't you just destructure the arguments? i.e. `resolve(parent,{arg1,arg2},ctx) =>…` No "parsing" is normally required.

Comment: @MichelFloyd I've submitted a feature request on GraphQL Github's page if you want to check it out to get a better understanding of what I was trying to do: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js/issues/3789